# How to get an image for a "Star" (Favorite) UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new to iOS. I'm looking to put a "Star" button on the top menu of my app. Is there a way to get the star button built into iOS similar to `UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd`

If not, how can I get an image similar to the common favorite(s) star used by Apple in iOS?

Similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple and quick way is to use [FontawesomeKit](https://github.com/PrideChung/FontAwesomeKit).
You can easily create the button like this:

```
FAKFontAwesome *icon = [FAKFontAwesome starIconWithSize:20];
[icon addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *favButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[icon imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(20, 20)]
                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                        target:self
                                                        action:@selector(doSomething:)];
```

Comment: The icon is not responding to the foreground color attribute: I want to make mine red, but its always blue (color of all bar button items)

Comment: If you are using it in a button you might want to set its `tintColor` property to change the button's color. If you are using it in a tab bar item, note that the image is always filled with the tab bar's tint color when active, the image color is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. But if you want some icons, you can check [this link](https://www.iconfinder.com/), [another one](http://blog.twg.ca/2010/11/retina-display-icon-set/).

**EDIT:**

You can also extract the Artwork of a component: See [this repository](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor)

Answer (score 0):

Following up what andreamazz said, here's code to have a colored star (favorite) button in the navBaritem (swift):

```
    let favAwesome = FAKFontAwesome.starIconWithSize(30.0) as FAKFontAwesome
    favAwesome.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.whiteColor())
    let favBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    favBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)
    favBtn.setImage(favAwesome.imageWithSize(CGSizeMake(30, 30)), forState: .Normal)
    favBtn.addTarget(self, action: "favorite", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    // favBarBtn is a class instance so we can access in the action method
    favBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: favBtn)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = favBarBtn

    // your custom code here to find isFavorite
    if isFavorite {
        favBtn.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else  {
        favBtn.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
```

then there is the "favorite" method to change the color (and set/unset favorite):

```
 func favorite() {
    // your custom favoriting code here
    let favBtn = favBarBtn?.customView as UIButton!
    if isFavorite {
        favBtn.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {
        favBtn.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
}
```